# why np.log(np.exp(x)) not equal to x?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

why np.log(np.exp()) does not return input in this case?

```py
_temp['pct'].values == np.log(np.exp(_temp['pct'].values))
```

returns

```py
array([False,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False])
```

Comment: Because of float arithmetic error. Use no.allclose to check up to machine precision

Comment: If you look closely, most values will be relatively close, but not perfectly equal. This is due to floating point precision: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken